# Has Batman ever gotten magical powers?

Tags: dc, batman

We know Batman has gotten superpowers of one kind or another, from Lantern rings, to enhanced capacities, to a super pill to the use of the Mobius chair... but has he ever gotten any supernatural abilities or purely *magical* powers before?

I'm speaking here of post-Crisis or modern Batman;  that time he was turned into a genie doesn't count (because the "funny book" 40s and 50s were *weird*).

In an *Elsewords* story, he was once bitten by Dracula and turned into a vampire, but that's all I remember. I know he studied escape artistry with Zattana's father, but I don't think he was imparted with any actual magical skills.

Are there any in-canon stories where this happened? What were those powers, and how long did he have them for?

Comment: Batman has gotten magical powers so many times, it's gonna be a task putting them all down, and any answer will be plagued with "me too" answers for years to come

Comment: A bunch of examples here; https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Batman-learn-how-to-use-magic

Comment: Some more examples; https://www.reddit.com/r/DCcomics/comments/5rvg82/stories_where_batman_uses_magic/